# Will docker-compose pull new images or use cache if new update is pushed to an image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, elastic-container-registry

i am using AWS ECR to host my images. when i push a new update to an existing image and run docker-compose up, will it detect that there is a new image in registry or will it used the cached version?

Comment: I can't help but think this would be easy to test?

Answer (score 0):

Docker will use the cached version unless you do something along the following lines:

- Delete the images manually on the Docker nodes
- Update your deployment to specify a new tag